# Mysqli to display link to profile page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for the best way for a user to be able to click on a link displayed on each row from mysql results page which will take them to a page which displays all the with regards to the id from that row.

HTML TABLE

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT firstName, lastName, id FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<table border='1px'>";
echo "<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Link</th></tr>";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<tr>
<td>{$row['firstName']}</td>
<td>{$row['lastName']}</td>
<td> LINK HERE </td>
</tr>";

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

    echo "</table>";
?>
```

USER PAGE

```
$sql = "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE id="????";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: In your URL you should have the id of the user (eg ../user/1). This would show you the details of the user with id 1. Creating a link would be easy because the href attribute of your a would contain that $row['id"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the information in the URL query string:

```
http://www.example.con/user.html?id=123456
```

Where the '123456' is the ID in the database for the user. This will be available in the GET array;

```
$_GET['id']
```

So now you can use that variable in your query to get the user's info for the page

**Warning**
[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

**EDIT**

I also noticed that you had this:

```
<td> LINK HERE </td>
```

Here is how your link would look:

```
<td><a href=\"user.html?id=" . $row['id'] . "\">link text</a></td>
```

Comment: Where exactly do I place the $_GET['id'] ?

Comment: @PeterGilbertson that is just a variable, you “place” it wherever you need the passed value …

Comment: In the context of your original question @PeterGilbertson you would use the variable in your query `WHERE id = $_GET['id']` but make sure to heed the warning about SQL injection.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT firstName, lastName, id FROM users WHERE id = $_GET'id';";

This is what I am using.

Comment: That's not correct, you're missing some brackets @PeterGilbertson